# How to retrieve data from a SmartContract that is not listed in their ABI

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm trying to retrieve the total supply of an ERC1155 SmartContract. This code was made by my friend and has been deployed. He took the code from OpenZeppelin with Burnable and Pausable presets.

The function `totalSupply` that I am trying to retrieve exists in the code. But, when I see the ABI, the `totalSupply` does not included.

(Sorry for small screenshot. Please see this screenshot in the new tab)
[image]

`MyErc1155Contract` compiled

[image]

This is where to get the ABI

[image]

Full code is here: [click_this_to_go_to_pastebin](https://pastebin.com/iffYckCY)

Then I am trying to write smartcontract to retrieve the `totalSupply`;

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract TotSup {

    uint256 public hasilBal;
    uint256 public hasil;

    function balanceOf(address erc1155_address, 
        address user_address, 
        uint256 nft_id) public {

        (bool successA, bytes memory resultA) = 
            erc1155_address.call(abi.encodeWithSignature(
                "balanceOf(address,uint256)", 
                user_address, 
                nft_id
        ));

        hasil = abi.decode(resultA, (uint256));

    }

    function bal(address erc1155_address, uint256 nft_id) public {
        (bool successA, bytes memory resultA) = 
            erc1155_address.call(
                abi.encodeWithSignature("totalSupply(uint256)", nft_id
        ));

        hasilBal = abi.decode(resultA, (uint256)); 
    }

}
```

I test my idea with writing another function `balanceOf` and it works perfectly.
And for the totalSupply in function `bal` is fail.

Is it possible to retrieve or calling function which is not included in the ABI? If yes, how to achieve that? And last, why call balanceOf still need for paying gas for just retrieving the data?

Comment: After code inspection, I found ERC1155Supply which is contains `totalSupply` code not included anywhere in the code. So, this is the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When a function exists in the code when you compile the code it reflects in the ABI, Without the function signature, you can't call the function.

As for your second answer, `balanceOf` in `TotSup` will cost you gas as it is not a view function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I edit my question and added more screenshot to strengthen my argument that the `totalSupply` not exists in the ABI. Do you have any idea how to call the `totalSupply`?